# Select SVG paths of group by group id using lxml

Tags: python, svg, lxml

I am having trouble selecting a particular set of paths using lxml. The SVG structure looks like this

```
<!DOCTYPE svg PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD SVG 1.1//EN" "http://www.w3.org/Graphics/SVG/1.1/DTD/svg11.dtd">
<!-- Created with matplotlib (http://matplotlib.org/) -->
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" height="288pt" version="1.1" viewBox="0 0 432 288" width="432pt">
    <defs>
        <style type="text/css">
            *{stroke-linecap:butt;stroke-linejoin:round;}
        </style>
    </defs>
    <g id="figure_1">
        <g id="patch_1">
            <path d=" M0 288 L432 288 L432 0 L0 0 z " style="fill:#ffffff;"/>
        </g>
        <g id="patch_2">
            <path d=" M0 288 L432 288 L432 0 L0 0 z " style="fill:#ffffff;"/>
        </g>
    <g id="axes_1">
        <g id="Poly3DCollection_1">
            <path clip-path="url(#pe61355d493)" d=" M195.211 34.2225 L194.801 34.0894 L196.527 212.986 L196.909 212.999 z " style="fill:#0000ff;"/>
            <path clip-path="url(#pe61355d493)" d=" M195.504 34.3231 L195.211 34.2225 L196.909 212.999 L197.184 213.022 z " style="fill:#0000ff;"/>
...
```

Its the paths listed at the bottom that I want to select and change their styles but I can't seem to get the syntax right and I fail to select the paths

```
ifilename = "myfig.svg"
with open( ifilename, 'r') as infile: 
tree = etree.parse( infile )

elements = tree.findall(".//g[@id='Poly3DCollection_1'") 
new_style = 'stroke-width:4px; stroke: linear-gradient(orange, darkblue)'

for child in elements:
    child.attrib['style'] = new_style

mod_svg = 'myfigmod.svg'
tree.write(mod_svg)
```

---

EDIT

so this gets me the element I want in this instance but I would still like a specific way of getting this element

```
root = tree.getroot()
for child in root[1][2][0]:
    child.attrib['style'] = new_style
```

Comment: [Looks like you are missing the svg namespace](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10494517/1572077)

Comment: I tried adding `SVG_NS = "http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
elements = tree.findall(".//g[@id='Poly3DCollection_1']" .format(SVG_NS))` but its having no effect.

Comment: You dropped a `]`in your xpath definition

Comment: Thanks for the help! What is the SVG_NS doing in the findall search? This works for me to get the path data from my SVG file that I loaded... but I have no idea why I can't just do `tree.findall("path")` to get the (in my case) single path element in the file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no get_element_by_id in etree, so you have to use xpath, like you are doing to grab the element.  I created your file and ran the code below and was able to change the style of the group.

```
element = tree.findall(".//{%s}g[@id='Poly3DCollection_1']" % SVG_NS)[0]
element.attrib["style"] = new_style
```

Comment: Thanks, unfortunately this didn't help. I dont think this is a namespace issue - see my edit to the original post where I can get the element using the root and list order

Comment: That code didnt quite work for me (I probably didnt explain what I wanted very well), but it got me nearly all the way there to this working code `element = tree.findall(".//{%s}g[@id='Poly3DCollection_1']" % SVG_NS)[0]
for child in element:
    child.attrib['style'] = new_style` Thanks so much